# SharePoint 2013 Development - Picture Library Not Appearing

Tags: 2013, picture-library, team-sites

When I go to 'Add an App' under Site Contents, I do not get a Photo Library as a choice.
I only see Document Library, Custom List, and tasks.

I believe this site was set up as a team site.

Any advice as to how I can add this app as a selection

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution for existing sites.  But deactivating and reactivating the Team Collaboration List feature as described below worked with new sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is team site and picture library app not showing, try to deactivate and reactivate the Team Collaboration List feature. Close all browser and open a fresh session.
also try to create a new subsite in the same site collection with team site template and check it their.if failed then try to create a new site collection with team template in same web app and then check the status.

Comment: This worked, the new site that I created did have all the other apps including the picture library.  But what does this mean for the site I already have set up?  Is there away that I can get these app choices back in the original site?

Answer (score 3):

Activate the **"Team Collaboration Lists"** site feature on the site.  You can do so by going to `Site Settings > Manage Site Features` (under the Site Actions section).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but 'Team Collaboration Lists' is already activated.

Comment: Try deactivating and reactivating it.

Comment: I tried this and it still did not work.  I still only see Document Library, Custom List, & Tasks within my existing site.

Answer (score 0):

In place of Picture Library you can go for Asset Library, it serves the same purpose . Like it accepts pictures too you can easliy drag and drop pictures to it.

Comment: An Asset library is not an option for me.  I only see Document Library, Custom List, and Tasks as app choices.